# Connecting to specific wifi in android 10

Tags: android, wifi, networkmanager

I'm trying to connect to a specific wifi network in android 10.  I already have the credentials available to me, and i'm adding the network suggestion:

```
val suggestion = WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
    .setSsid("ssid")
    .setWpa2Passphrase("password")
    .build()

wifiManager.removeNetworkSuggestions(mutableListOf(suggestion))
when (wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(mutableListOf(suggestion))) {
    WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS -> {
        networkAdded()
    }
    WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_ERROR_ADD_DUPLICATE -> {
        networkDuplicate()
    }
    else -> {
        networkAddFailed()
    }
}
```

I'm able to see the notification (though only the first time the app requests this, which makes sense for the most part, since it's asking for permission really to be able to suggest networks).  However, after I allow it, i can't seem to get connected to that network.  In particular if i already have a wifi connection to some other network.

The new network does not appear in my list of saved networks, and if i find it in the wifi scan list, and click on it, it treats it like a new network.

I don't expect the app to be able to force the system to connect, but i would expect the user to be able to do it on their own via the wifi settings without having to configure it from scratch.

I've also tried using ConnectivityManager to forcibly connect, but that does not add an actual persistent wifi connection.  It's only meant to force connection for a specific app while the app is in memory (at least that's my understanding of it).

Comment: Hi Matt, I was wondering if you were able to find a solution to this?

Comment: Actually, I just discovered that you need to not be currently connected to any networks for it to work. If you aren't connected to any other networks, the suggestion will be connected to.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but after I added this piece of code the device was connected to the network:

```
final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.ACTION_WIFI_NETWORK_SUGGESTION_POST_CONNECTION);

final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (!intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.ACTION_WIFI_NETWORK_SUGGESTION_POST_CONNECTION)) {
            return;
        } else {
            // Do something with success
        }
    }
};
context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Hope that it helps. You can find the complete code example in: [Wi-Fi suggestion API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-suggest)